# Groovy script fails to call Slack notification parameter from Jenkins DSL job

Tags: groovy, slack, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm attempting to use the Jenkins Job DSL plugin for the first time to create some basic job "templates" before getting into more complex stuff.

Jenkins is running on a Windows 2012 server. The Jenkins version is 1.650 and we are using the Job DSL plugin version 1.51.

Ideally what I would like is for the seed job to be parameterised so that when it is being run the user can enter four things: the Job DSL script location, the name of the generated job, a Slack channel for failure notifications, and an email address for failure notifications.

The first two are fine: I can call the parameters in the groovy script, for example the script understands `job("${JOB_NAME}")` and takes the name I enter for the job when I run the seed job.

However when I try to do the same thing with a Slack channel the groovy script doesn't seem to want to play.  Note that if I specify a Slack channel rather than trying to call a parameter it works fine.

My Job DSL script is here:

```
job("${JOB_NAME}") {
    triggers {
        cron("@daily")
    }
    steps {
        shell("echo 'Hello World'")
    }
    publishers {
    slackNotifier {
      room("${SLACK_CHANNEL}")
      notifyAborted(true)
      notifyFailure(true)
      notifyNotBuilt(false)
      notifyUnstable(true)
      notifyBackToNormal(true)
      notifySuccess(false)
      notifyRepeatedFailure(false)
      startNotification(false)
      includeTestSummary(false)
      includeCustomMessage(false)
      customMessage(null)
      buildServerUrl(null)
      sendAs(null)
      commitInfoChoice('NONE')
      teamDomain(null)
      authToken(null)
    }
  }
    logRotator {
        numToKeep(3)
        artifactNumToKeep(3)
    publishers {
        extendedEmail {
            recipientList('me@mydomain.com')
            defaultSubject('Seed job failed')
            defaultContent('Something broken')
            contentType('text/html')
            triggers {
              failure ()
              fixed ()
              unstable ()
                stillUnstable {
                    subject('Subject')
                    content('Body')
                    sendTo {
                        developers()
                        requester()
                        culprits()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But starting the seed job fails and gives me this output:

```
Started by user 
Building on master in workspace D:\data\jenkins\workspace\tutorial-job-dsl-2
Disk space threshold is set to :5Gb
Checking disk space Now 
Total Disk Space Available is: 28Gb
 Node Name: master
Running Prebuild steps
Processing DSL script jobBuilder.groovy
ERROR: (jobBuilder.groovy, line 10) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.structs.DescribableContext.room() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [#dev]
Possible solutions: wait(), find(), dump(), grep(), any(), wait(long)
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is the first time I have tried to do anything with Groovy and I'm sure it's a basic error but would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, that's a bug in Job DSL, see [JENKINS-39153](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39153).

You actually do not need to use the template string syntax `"${FOO}"` if you just want to use the value of `FOO`. All parameters are string variables which can be used directly:

```
job(JOB_NAME) {
  // ...
  publishers {
    slackNotifier {
      room(SLACK_CHANNEL)
      notifyAborted(true)
      notifyFailure(true)
      notifyNotBuilt(false)
      notifyUnstable(true)
      notifyBackToNormal(true)
      notifySuccess(false)
      notifyRepeatedFailure(false)
      startNotification(false)
      includeTestSummary(false)
      includeCustomMessage(false)
      customMessage(null)
      buildServerUrl(null)
      sendAs(null)
      commitInfoChoice('NONE')
      teamDomain(null)
      authToken(null)
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

This syntax is more concise and does not trigger the bug.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I didn't find that when I was searching because that's a pretty clear cut explanation. Anyway it works now so thanks for the help.

Comment: I should clarify - thanks for both pointing out the bug as well as the fact that the string variables can be used directly.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the Jobs DSL Plugin, versions 1.53 and greater: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/81090b549b9c238f3fc09b2c06a7eaa2d69b3ea4/docs/Home.md#release-notes